# How to configure a response class which inherits from a class which takes in a Generic in Spring boot Java with Spring swagger annotations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, swagger, spring-annotations

I am getting the vulnerability "An array schema does not specify the maximum number of items it can contain" for my open-APi file generated by springfox 3.0.0

Its a spring boot application and the
controller and Response class are something like this,

```
`public class Controller {
    @GetMapping(value = "/getPath")
    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public class BaseResponse<T> {
        T result;
    }

    public class Response extends BaseResponse<List<QueryResult>> {
        //attributes
    }


    public class QueryResult {
        //result data attributes
    }
}`
```

When I am passing a list to the generic of BaseResponse, how to define the max number of Array elements
using swagger annotations in my code? If anyone had faced a similar issues with the swagger configurations for generic class definitions please help me out.
Also, the BaseResponse is a library class and I wont be able to modify it.

The definition I am getting is,

"Response": {
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"result": {
"type": "array",
"items": {
"$ref": "#/definitions/QueryResult"
}
}
}
But I need something like this,

"Response": {
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"result": {
"type": "array",
"maxItems": 10,
"items": {
"$ref": "#/definitions/QueryResult"
}
}
}

I tried using @Size, @ApiResponse with @ArraySchema but I am not able to get the maxItems in my generated swagger file.